# Shiro / Vaadin loses session at page reload

Tags: vaadin, reload, shiro

I added Shiro session management (based on [Kim's and Leif's webinar](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNAo3ApWA-A)) to the Vaadin quick ticket dashboard demo application. When I do a browser reload in the application I get thrown back to the login page with no session. How / where can I prevent this.

I have a  standard shiro.ini setup

Login button handler:

```
        signin.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
            boolean loginOK = false;

            Factory<SecurityManager> factory = 
                    new IniSecurityManagerFactory("classpath:shiro.ini");
            SecurityManager securityManager = factory.getInstance();
            SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager((org.apache.shiro.mgt.SecurityManager) 
                                                            securityManager);

            Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();

            //collect user principals and credentials in a gui specific manner 
            //such as username/password html form, X509 certificate, OpenID, etc.
            //We'll use the username/password example here since it is the most common.
            UsernamePasswordToken token = 
                    new UsernamePasswordToken(username.getValue(), password.getValue());

            //this is all you have to do to support 'remember me' (no config - built in!):
            token.setRememberMe(true);

            //currentUser.login(token);
            try {
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "trying login");
                currentUser.login( token );
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "login done");

                    //if no exception, that's it, we're done!
            } catch ( Exception e ) {
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "exception");
            }

            if ( currentUser.hasRole( "schwartz" ) ) {
                loginOK = true;
            } else {
                loginOK = false;
            }

            if (loginOK) {
                signin.removeShortcutListener(enter);
                buildMainView();
            } else {
                if (loginPanel.getComponentCount() > 2) {
                    // Remove the previous error message
                    loginPanel.removeComponent(loginPanel.getComponent(2));
                }
                // Add new error message
                Label error = new Label(
                        "Wrong username or password. <span>Hint: try empty values</span>",
                        ContentMode.HTML);
                error.addStyleName("error");
                error.setSizeUndefined();
                error.addStyleName("light");
                // Add animation
                error.addStyleName("v-animate-reveal");
                loginPanel.addComponent(error);
                username.focus();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use @preserveonRefresh annotation in UI init class

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Shiro's web filter. This way, your session will not be lost and you can prohibit unauthorized actions (e.g. Instantiating view objects) easily since Shiro's context is already set up when you display the login or any other view.